# Как хранить логические выражение в базе данных?

Tags: sql, база-данных, структуры-данных, реляционная-модель

В общем проблема такая, я составляю схему БД для оболочки экспертных систем. Суть экспертной системы такая: у нее есть множество правил в виде продукций `IF:...` `THEN:...`. Я не могу составить схему для посылки правила, так как посылка может содержать сколь угодно вложенных конструкций. Например: `IF: ((VAR1 > 7) AND (VAR2 < 10)) OR ...` .
Есть вот такой набросок, но он позволяет хранить правило лишь с двумя сравнениями, соединенными логически. А еще скобки могут менять порядок. Если провести связь саму в себя у сущности логическая операция, но тогда две логических операции так же должны быть связаны логически. В общем вот. Может кому приходилось сталкиваться с такого рода проблемой, или я занимаюсь абсолютной фигней и так никто не делает?
[image: Схема]

Comment: Не очень понятно, что вы хотите изобразить и для чего? Для хранения какой либо логики используются хранимые процедуры/функции и т.д. в самой БД. Если ваши правила задаются из вне, то можно их сохранить в виде текста, а обрабатывать через какую то процедуру, которая из текста соберет динамический sql-запрос и выполнит его. Однако это может быть проблемой, с точки зрения безопасности БД(риск SQL инъекции)

Comment: @SwaD нет нет. В общем есть текст программы (экспертной системы). Мне именно эти условия в посылках нужно просто хранить, и потом получать. А я не знаю как их хранить, не могу придумать множество сущностей и связей для их хранения.